Would a single Nextjs project file without color be a problem?
I'm using typescript in next js in version 14.2.7, it's the only code that doesn't have color and I can't say that it's working 100%.
in the src/app/templates/Dashboards/index.tsx directory

tsconfig:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "noEmit": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    ".next/types/**/*.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    "src/app/loading.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}

